# Can't start glassfish v3 on windows 7

Tags: windows, glassfish-3

I have glassfish v3 on windows 7 installed, but it won't start on 8080. I get typical dead page when I go to 8080 like you would expect if it's not running.

I tried to start it manually. 
C:\glassfish3\bin
asadmin start-domain  and what i get is "system cannot find the path specified"

I searched hi and low for an answer but most questions involve glassfish not starting because the port is not free. however that's not my issue.

I've tried reinstalling about a half dozen times and even rebooting. nothing changes

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An alternative answer:

Download the zip version here:
http://download.java.net/glassfish/3.1.2/release/glassfish-3.1.2.zip

Unzip this to c:\glassfish3

This command *will* work:

```
C:\glassfish3\bin\asadmin.bat start-domain domain1
```

Comment: that did it thanks. it must have been something with the windows installer. thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear it buddy. Post back to StackOverflow if you have more questions or checkout their FAQ. GF friggen rocks!

Answer (score 9):

Its a configuration issue, when you try to install glassfish server from the installer sans bundled jdk,simply go to "\glassfish3\glassfish\config", set AS_JAVA to jdk home dir in asenv.bat file, re-run the installation, chose custom installation and "configure an existing installation" and you are done.

For more info:http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16155.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot a slash in your command. The error your getting isn't a glassfish error, it's a DOS error.

try:

C:\glassfish3\bin\asadmin.bat start-domain domain1

or

C:\glassfish3\bin\asadmin start-domain domain1

Comment: already did that same response " system cannot find path specified" maybe something is wrong with windows because that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was facing the same issue. I am able to resolve the same issue by following below steps:

Go to \glassfish\config (Note: In my case it is c:\glassfish3\glassfish\config)

Now open asenv.bat in notepad.

Make the value of AS_JAVA same as JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Now open command prompt and go to the bin folder and run asadmin start-domain domain1.

If you are getting error that no domain exist then create new domain by following below link:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4497/create-domain-1/index.html